# How to say "edge" in Italian?

Tags: translation, single-words, mathematics

Buongiorno,

Volevo sapere come si dice "edge" in italiano, con l'interpretazione matematica corrispondente all'inglese "there is an edge connecting the two nodes, of the graph, whereas in the digraph the corresponding two nodes are connected by an arc". Come si tradurrebbe questa frase? Chiedo perché, nonostante comune, la definizione non è contenuta nel dizionario WordReference online: [Edge](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/edge).

Grazie.

Comment: I suppose you refer to  [graph theory](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_dei_grafi).

Comment: You can find the technical vocabulary in the Wikipedia article linked above. So, as you can see, "edge" is translated as "spigolo".

Comment: @Charo I am far from expert in combinatorics, but *arco* is much more common in my experience

Comment: And also *lato*, sorry I had forgot about it.

Comment: @DenisNardin: E io non ho nemmeno dimestichezza col vocabolario matematico in italiano!

Comment: Even in English I would recommend against setting a distinction between *arc* and *edge* in a graph, because whether an arc is directed or not is widely inconsistent in the literature. I would rather use *directed/undirected edge* if it is important (clarity beats concision, every time)

Comment: Lo so che non è bello sciorinare il proprio CV, ma ho un dottorato in matematica (preso a Roma) e mi sono occupato di combinatoria e dintorni. Ho sempre detto e sentito dire sia “spigoli” che “archi”; per un grafo orientato, il termine corrispondente è appunto “spigolo orientato” o “arco orientato”.

Comment: Un'aggiunta personale: “spigolo” ha per me il pregio di avere un parallelo con la geometria classica, dove gli spigoli sono i segmenti che congiungono due vertici di un poliedro.

Comment: @DaG: Sei la persona ideale per scrivere una risposta.

Comment: Grazie, @Charo, ma in questo momento non ho sotto mano fonti oggettive. Avendo un po' di tempo si potrebbero cercare in rete dispense di corsi di teoria dei grafi (e dintorni: combinatoria, reti etc.) e fare una piccola statistica sui termini usati.

Comment: Grazie post le vostre risposte. Qualcuno mi potrebbe anche magari spiegare cosa significa la parola dintorni in questo contesto matematico?  Il singolare di grafi è per caso grafo.

Comment: Capisco come edge possa essere stato tradotto spigolo e arc arco, (in informatica, programmando, la distinzione in fatti conviene perché ci fa scrivete di meno facendoci focalizzare sul concetto in questione di più).

Comment: La parola spigolo in italiano mi dà l'idea comunque di toccare qualcosa di più solido (come appunto un lato di un mobile o di un poliedro) anche se forse mi sbaglio, edge poteva anche essere rappresentato da un filo di vario spessore e forma di plastica o gomma o magari anche un cappello nell'immaginazione, spigolo da più l'idea della presenza del tridimensionalismo e del dolore al tatto se toccato (dato che si tratta di qualcosa di appuntito).

Comment: @DaG, in combinatoria e dintorni, what does dintorni refer to? Thanks.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson Il singolare di grafi è grafo. Non ho mai sentito la parola *dintorni* usata in un contesto matematico, per caso forse ti riferisci a *intorni* (neighborhoods)?

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson: Usavo “dintorni” nel senso che il dizionario Treccani dà [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dintorno) al punto 2.a. Si usa dire “[qualcosa] e dintorni” per dire “...e altre cose simili, imparentate”. Non è un termine matematico!

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson: Ricorda che “spigolo” si usa in geometria anche per indicare i lati dei poligoni che costituiscono le facce di un poliedro (per capirci, la caratteristica di Eulero dà il valore di #facce – #spigoli + #vertici). E lo “scheletro” di un poliedro (i suoi vertici e i suoi spigoli) è un esempio classico di grafo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see on the [Italian Wikipedia page for graph](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafo), edges are usually called *lati*, *archi* or *spigoli*. In my experience the latter name is very rare outside of schoolbooks (and by this I literally mean books used in high school or below, not university textbooks), but it's been a lot of years since I had to speak about math in Italian.

To give a perhaps more authoritative reference, you can look at [this lecture](http://olimpiadi.dm.unibo.it/videolezioni/Training/Senior_13/Basic/Video/S13B_C2-1-phi.avi) at around the timestamp 19:25 where the lecturer explicitly says that the Italian name for the edges is *archi*.

Comment: I always use “lati” for the edges of a graph, but I acknowledge that “archi” is used as well.

Comment: In my case "archi" is actually a lot more common than the other terms. I've studied/used graphs in multiple courses at the university where I'm studying and I've always used only "archi"

Comment: So basically the alternatives are spigoli, archi, and lati. I like lati, it sounds softer than the other alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson For what is worth I recommend *archi* which in my experience is the most used, followed by *lati* (I dislike *spigoli*, I never liked it even for polyhedra...)

Answer (score 4):

*Edge* significa spigolo o bordo quando siamo in ambito puramente geometrico.

Ad esempio nella modellazione tridimensionale assistita da calcolatore (sistemi CAD) gli edge sono i bordi delle superfici e, in presenza di solidi, rappresentano anche gli spigoli delle loro facce. La parola non fa riferimento alla forma dello spigolo quindi non va limitata ai soli poliedri ma a qualunque solido di forma libera.

Venendo alle entità che uniscono i nodi in un grafo si utilizzano comunemente i termini *arco* e *spigolo* come si può riscontrare [qui](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafo). Aggiungo, per rinforzare il riferimento alla geometria solida, che i nodi di un grafo possono essere chiamati anche *vertici*.