# Multilingual dictionaries of mathematical terms

Tags: vocabulary, resources, mathematics

Having posted [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9463/how-to-say-edge-in-italian), I now wonder whether there are any dictionaries, online, good ones, which would provide multilingual translations of technical words used in mathematics, including English to Italian and others. Any online such dictionaries would be preferred. Thanks.

Comment: @DaG I think it’s up to you to deal with this question;-)

Comment: Indeed, @abarisone, and doubly so, as a mathematician and as a translator! :) Unfortunately, I don't know of such a reliable, online dictionary. I happen to use (as everybody) Wikipedia, looking for a term in a language, and then seeing the links to the corresponding articles in other languages. But this is not a reliable procedure, since the links may be broken, the choice of the other-language term may be up to the personal taste of whomever edited the article and so on. One can start like this and then double- and triple-check what they found.

Comment: Universitat de Barcelona has [this](http://www.ub.edu/ubterm/obres/matematiques-vocabulari.xml) (it's something very old: it existed already in the form of a little book when I began university) but, unfortunately it doesn't include Italian. I wonder if any Italian university has done something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has these lists:

- https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progetto:Matematica/Traduzioni

comprising English/Italian, French/Italian, German/Italian (and vice versa).

Comment: That's probably the best thing available. Unfortunately it is lacking almost every term in my area (homotopy theory)... I guess we have our work cut out for us :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not technically a dictionary, but you can use **Wikipedia's inter-wiki links** to get translations of technical terms. For instance:

1. Go to the page of [CW complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex)
2. Scroll down until you see "Languages" in the left sidebar (or click on the icon in the mobile view)
3. Click on "Italian"
4. Get redirected to [Complesso di celle](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complesso_di_celle). Profit!

In my experience, this method is very reliable and translations exist for a wide range of words.